# ASP.NET MVC Checkbox List Validation

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

as of right now I am validating checkbox list in the model by overriding the IsValid function so it will get validated on the server-side, but I was wondering if there's a way to add validation on the client-side. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. Here to help...

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery validate unobtrusive script.
For this you would require to put DataAnnotation attributes to your model class

something like following

```
public class Model
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Name is required")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Name can not be greater than 50")]
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

And include the following scripts in your view

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I have done that and I thought the same that adding the required attribute will validate the checkbox list, but for some reason it doesn't.

Comment: okay, I understand your problem. Is it like selecting one of the checkbox ?